# CSS ::Deep Pseudo-Element Not Working in Blazor with .NET 5 & 6

Tags: css, blazor, blazor-server-side, pseudo-element

I have a Blazor app that I was running in Visual Studio 2019/.NET 5 and then, due to this issue, I moved to Visual Studio 2022/.NET 6 and upgraded the Blazor app accordingly.

Unfortunately, I am still getting a **"::deep" is not a valid pseudo-element** error is the IDE and the styles are NOT being applied.  Here is the class in my MainLayout.razor.css stylesheet:

```css
.deviceWrapper, ::deep .deviceWrapper {
    border-radius: 5px;
    height: 100px;
    width: 400px;
    background-color: #f6f6f6;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.26), 0 2px 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), 0 3px 1px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
}
```

Here is the razor page code to which this styles are not being applied!

```html
<div class="target-wrapper" style="width:400px">
    <div class="deviceWrapper">
      <TelerikContextMenu IdField="@menuId" Selector="@targetNameWithDot" Data="@MenuItems" OnClick="@((ContextMenuItem item) => OnItemClick(item, @thisDevice.DeviceIDHash))">
      </TelerikContextMenu>
      <div class="@targetName" style="text-align:right;">
        <span class="material-icons-outlined md-light">menu</span>
      </div>
      <div width="100%">
        My Context Menu Is Above!
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Neither the deviceWrapper nor the material-icons-outlined md-light styles are being applied.

My _Host.cshtml Head looks as follows:

```html
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <base href="~/" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link href="vBear-Frontend.styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="_content/Telerik.UI.for.Blazor.Trial/css/kendo-theme-default/all.css" />
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
```

Any I missing a CSS attribute or is there some other way to apply CSS styles to child elements?

Thank you!

Answer (score -3, accepted):

As it turns out, I needed to add a CSS stylesheet directly to my Razor page, remove all entries from the main site.css and MainLayout.razor.css files and now everything works great - no ::deep required!